# use textwrap.shorten with a list

Tags: python, matplotlib, pie-chart

this code creates me a table in an excel file and a pie plot, the label fields, taken from a list of values, are way too long.

```
    plt.pie(df.Confronto.value_counts(),
        labels=textwrap.shorten(df.Confronto.value_counts().index.tolist(), width=10, placeholder="..."))
    plt.title("Confronto {} - {}".format(Mese,Mese2,))
    plt.show()
```

So I tried to shorten it using text.shorten, but it gives me this error:

```
labels=textwrap.shorten(df.Confronto.value_counts().index.tolist(), width=10, placeholder="...")) 
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'strip'
```

I tried to cast but it gave me an error about the indeterminate length of the label

```
labels=textwrap.shorten(str(df.Confronto.value_counts().index.tolist()), width=10, placeholder="...")

raise ValueError("'label' must be of length 'x'")
ValueError: 'label' must be of length 'x'
```

The image below shows the result of the code in its current state: the labels are too long and at the time the image is created nothing is read, I wish I could put a maximum on the length of the labels.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure as to what you are trying to achieve with this code, so I'll just explain why the exception is raised. That happens because `pandas.Index.tolist` returns a list, and `textwrap.shorten` is used on strings. So, cannot strip a string if it's a list.

I assume `df.Confronto.value_counts().index.tolist()` returns a list of `int`, like `[1,2,3]`. You may try joining the list first with

```
label_string = ''.join(map(str,[1,2,3]))
Out: '123'
```

It first maps `str()` over your list of `int` to produce a list of `str`, then joins the list in a single string with a `''` symbol.

However, `labels=` takes the list of `str`, so you might want to restore it back to list with

```
label_list = [ch for ch in label_string]
```

or even slice the original `df.Confronto.value_counts().index.tolist()` to reduce the number of elements, and then map `str()` over it.

After clarification in comments I suggest a list comprehension to iterate textwrap on given list:

```
label_list = [textwrap.shorten(string, width=10, placeholder="...") for string in df.Confronto.value_counts().index.tolist()]
```

Comment: if I run "print(df.Confronto.value_counts().index.tolist())" :
['[eks][easytrade] BrokerService.dll broker-service-* on port 80', 'collector-trace-exporter', '[eks][easytrade] SpringBoot com.dynatrace.easytrade.creditcardorderservice.Application credit-card-order-service-* on port 8080', 'MF EasyTravelWebserver:8070', '[eks][easytrade] engine-* (/api)', '[eks][easytrade] SpringBoot com.dynatrace.easytrade.featureflagservice.Featureflagservi feature-flag-service-* on port 8080']
['azure Requests on localhost:8021', ...

Comment: So my assumption was wrong, it is a list of strings. Can you specifiy what exactly do you want to do with these strings? Do you want to shorten each of those?

Comment: Included a line to iterate textwrap in the answer

Comment: I added the image where you can see the result of the code in its current state: the labels are too long and by the time the image is created nothing is read, I wish I could put a maximum on the length of the labels